# Why is my question on splitting of d orbitals of cubic geometry off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My [question on splitting of d orbitals at cubic geometry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/91139/4945) was not homework question, not a single textbook is providing any answer, not even on the internet.

Comment: Hi Sayantan, I understand your concern. In the original question, you should've added your thoughts and reasoning. What was taught to you and how you tried to apply it there but it didn't work out. This was clearly missing from your previous question, hence it got put on hold. [Note that the "homework policy" does not only refer to only textbook-QA being closed, but in general any question that lacks effort in understanding the underlying concepts]